# How to resolve error "Cannot load JDBC driver class" displayed in jmeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I recently updated to jmeter 4.0 from jmeter 3.2. In jmx file, i have query to execute and it was running fine in jmeter 3.2 . But the jmx file fails with error "Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'" in jmeter 4.0. Please help me in resolving this issue.

below is the screenshot of JDBC Connection Configuration[image: JDBC connection config]

Comment: did you have in Test Plan library added manually? did you added JDBC jar to JMeter 4 lib folder?

Comment: I had added "sqljdbc41.jar" in apache-jmeter-4.0\lib path. Do i need to add any extra jars?

Comment: what's your java version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

1. Download [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)
2. Extract `mssql-jdbc-x.x.x.jrex.jar` somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up

See [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) and [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers) articles for more details on how to use JMeter for database testing.